# How To Save Database Changes to Drag and Drop Lists with Ajax in Asp.Net MVC5

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drag-and-drop, dragula

I am attempting to implement a Dragula Drag and Drop feature to the part of my application that allows an Admin to assign users to certain roles. The .cshtml is implemented and displaying correctly but am having trouble figuring out how to write the Ajax call so that I can pass parameters to my method in the controller that utilizes a helper class to add and remove. Can parameters be passed into the ajax $.post(url) that are derived from the location where it was dropped? Included below should be all relevant code. I also understand Viewbags aren't the best way to do this, but if i can get it functioning i will write a viewmodel and pass the data through that way instead.

### .cshtml Code

there are 4 of these, one for each of the 3 assignable roles, and one for those not assigned to any role. They're populating correctly currently.

```
<div class="col-3 h-100">
    <div class="bg-secondary p-4">
        <h6 class="card-title">Developers</h6>
        <div id="dragula-developers" class="py-2">
            @foreach (var user in ViewBag.Developers)
            {
                <div class="card rounded mb-2">
                    <div class="card-body p-3">
                        <div class="media">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h6 class="mb-1">@user.FirstName @user.LastName</h6>
                                <p class="mb-0 text-muted"> @user.Email </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

### Controller Method

```
public JsonResult ManageRoles(string id, string role)
        {
            var message = "User Not Assigned To Role";
            if (id != null)
            {
                userRolesHelper.RemoveUserFromRole(id, role);
                    
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(role))
                {
                    userRolesHelper.AddUserToRole(id, role);
                    message = "User Assigned To Role Successfully!";
                }
            }
            return Json(message);
        }
```

and finally the bare bones of my dragula script where my ajax should go i believe, after the .on('drop').

```
(function ($) {
            'use strict';
            dragula([document.getElementById("dragula-noRole"), document.getElementById("dragula-submitters"),
            document.getElementById("dragula-developers"), document.getElementById("dragula-managers")])
                .on('drop', function (el) {
                          console.log($(el));
                })
        })(jQuery);
```

There are 4 boxes, and ideally when a user's card is dropped into a dragula container, their id and the role associated with the dragula would be shot to the post and their role would be changed, returning a message. This isn't a feature that would be used heavily, so i shouldnt need websockets, but i can't figure out how to implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After much longer than I care to admit, I've finally figured it out. Just in case it helps anyone else in the future, I had to change my controller to accept an Array. It ended up looking like this before Abstraction.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ReassignToDev(Array userIds)
    {
        var message = "";
        if (userIds == null)
        {
            message = "No Users to Change Roles Of";
        }

        if (userIds != null)
        {
            foreach (var user in userIds)
            { 
                userRolesHelper.RemoveAllRoles(user.ToString());
                userRolesHelper.AddUserToRole(user.ToString(), "Developer");
                message = "Role Change Successful";
            }
        }

        return Json(message);
    }
```

and my ajax call finally wound up looking like this:

```
 var developerIds = new Array();
        $('.developer .hidden').each(function (i) {
            developerIds.push($(this).text());
        })
        console.log(developerIds);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ReassignToDev", "Admin")',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { userIds: developerIds },

            success: function (response) {
                alert(message);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(message);
            }
        });
```

4 different methods and 4 different calls, submitted through a button click that fires an ajax request. not the most elegant solution i'm sure, but it is functional and fast.